# How to add a category image menu to my shop page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add an additional menu consisting only of the product category images. I'm using woocommerce. I would like it to be centered in the middle of the page and drop down. What kind of short code does this require? I've tried using Mega Menu plugin but it only alters my primary menu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a direct way for that, You can use this code to get an array of the categories images URLs, You can use the "woocommerce_before_shop_loop" action then, loop over the array and put the images in the HTML form you like.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', function() {
    $categories = get_terms( 'product_cat' );
    $categories_thumbnails_urls = [];
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $category->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        if ( empty( $thumbnail_url ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        $categories_thumbnails_urls[] = $thumbnail_url;
    }

    foreach ( $categories_thumbnails_urls as $cat_thumb_url ) {
        // ...
    }
});
```